# Selecting joined columns Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, model

I'm trying to select a column of the joined table in my query, however it's coming up as a nil value

I've tried the following code:

```
SF
  .unscoped
  .joins("LEFT JOIN my_join_table ON sf.id = my_join_table.sf_id where my_join_table.queue_id = ",queue.id.to_s)
  .select("sf.*, my_join_table.`sf_read_only` as join_readonly")
```

I'm trying to access the value like `sfModels[0].join_readonly` but it's returning a nil value, even though in my db table it should only be equal to 0 or 1.

EDIT: I have now also tried

```
SF
  .unscoped
  .joins("LEFT JOIN my_join_table ON sf.id = my_join_table.sf_id where my_join_table.queue_id = ",queue.id.to_s)
  .includes(:filter_screen_flows)
```

This has not worked either though unfortunately. Calling `sfModels[0].sf_read_only` returns "`` NoMethodError: undefined method `sf_read_only' for #<SF:0x131a37fd> ``"

Comment: Isn't it `join_readonly` instead?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yes, sorry that's what I was trying, I've edited the question to reflect this. Sorry about that.

Comment: try accessing like `sfModels[0]['join_readonly']`

Comment: @Rthi ```NameError: undefined local variable or method `join_readonly' for #<Runtime::QueuesController:0x1f44d3cf>
from (pry):18:in `<eval>'```

Comment: you should be able to get the result in both of the ways 1. `sfModels[0].join_readonly` 2. `sfModels[0]['join_readonly']`. I checked in my side and works fine.

Comment: I've tried removing the backtick from ``` my_join_table.`sf_read_only` ``` however this hasn't made a difference unfortunately. Is your sfModels array holding models as well?

Comment: Can you share the value of the query result?  `sfModels` and `sfModels[0]`

Comment: sfModels: ```[#<SF:0x76fd2eca
  id: 1,
  application_id: 8,
  name: "edge Test",
  key: "edge_test",
  description: "">,
#<SF:0x449ac668
  id: 2,
  application_id: 8,
  name: "edgeTestSF",
  key: "edgetestsf",
  description: "">]```

sfModels[0]: ```#<SF:0x76fd2eca
 id: 1,
 application_id: 8,
 name: "edge Test",
 key: "edge_test",
 description: "">```

Comment: I think you're getting nil values because of the left join. If you just use a regular join you will only get SFs that have an id on the my_join_table.. `SF.joins(:my_join_table).where(my_join_table: { queue_id: queue.id })`

Comment: try:
`SF.unscoped.left_outer_joins(:my_join_table).where(my_join_table: { queue_id: queue.id.to_s }).group('sf.id')`. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins for more info.